# how can I set a vars value insted of the var

Tags: variables, button

I'm making buttons and when i make them i set the onclick to use i and i want them to use the value of i when the button was made not when it was clicked

i cannot make the buttons manually there are over 3000

```
while (i < 3634) {
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerText = swf[i];
button.type = "submit";
button.name = swf[i];
button.onclick = function () {
nes(swf[i])
};
button.classList.add("button");
document.body.appendChild(button); 
i++
}
```

`
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used the buttons name instead of setting the name and function separately

```
while (i < 3633) {
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerText = swf[i];
button.type = "submit";
button.name = swf[i];
button.id= swf[i];
button.onclick = function () {
nes(button.name)
};
button.id= button.id + swf[i] + ")";
button.classList.add("button");
document.body.appendChild(button); 
i++
}
```